# Does "pg_hba.conf" file have to be manually modified?

Tags: postgresql-9.3

I have been developing a stand-alone application (I mean I need to install the app to all client workstations separately.) which is working with a PostgreSQL database. At first, the database and my application were on the same machine. However, after having a working prototype, I migrated the database to a server (on different machine). The first time I ran my application, I was not successful in connecting to the database and figured it out by modifying `pg_hba.conf` file so that a client workstation could make a successful connection. Below is an example:

```
# host    DATABASE    USER     ADDRESS          METHOD    [OPTIONS]
  host    all         all      xx.xx.xx.xx/xx   MD5
```

I did a couple more of this and the list is growing steadily, as it should be. I was wondering whether is (I believe there should be) an easier or "neater" way of doing this so that I won't have to modify this file manually each time a new client is added to the system.

Thanks for your valuable time,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "address" part can be a subnet or (in later versions) a (textual) domain, so if you group your clients in suitable way, you can just configure a subnet or domain there.

Alternatively, you can just allow access to any address and use robust authentication to make sure only the right clients can get in.

Finally, you can also have pg_hba.conf automatically generated by your deployment software.